# How to comply to Disability Discrimination Act of 1995 while developing an iOS app

Tags: ios, user-interface

We have a requirement from our UK client in which he wants us to comply to [Disability Discrimination Act of 1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disability_Discrimination_Act_1995) while developing the iOS app. I tried to search about it on Internet but most of the information is available on `compliance by websites`. I think that it might be related to supporting accessibility in our app as stated in this link: [Accessibility on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/accessibility/ios/) .

Can the community members confirm if my understanding is right?

Comment: Since your question is specifically about legal obligations, I'm not sure it is relevant for this Stack Exchange. I'm sure people could answer a general question about "How do I make an app accessible?" but one specifically about a UK law (that only applies in Northern Ireland) seems off-topic.

Comment: I think that since there are some coding practices which people follow while developing the websites in order to comply to this law, there should be some practices which we need to follow while developing the iOS app, I want to know about the same. 'Accessibility' is a guess from me, may be community members can confirm if my understanding is right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking us to interpret a piece of legislation. There may be some pieces of this which can be asked at Law.SE, but overall you're simply going to have to talk to the client about what they think needs to be done to comply with the law. Or hire a lawyer.

Comment: I Googled the title of your question.  The first two matches are your question, asked in two different places.  The third match is this: http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/design-website-for-blind/  The fourth match led me here: https://www.w3.org/TR/WAI-WEBCONTENT/full-checklist.html

Comment: All of these guidelines are related to web content, might be this law is applicable to website development only?

Comment: @Devarshi I think this obligation is not just about websites.  Anyway, depending on your app, if it is connected somehow to a server, it might be difficult to argue that it's not web content.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know UK law, I'm not a legal expert, and I can't give you legal advise.  But this article should explain the legal [compliance aspects with UK DDA](http://www.out-law.com/page-330).

You'll see in this article -- and in many others -- that the recurring source on the accessibility requirements for disabled is the W3C consortium's **[WCAG 2.0 guideline](https://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/wcag)**.

Here you'll find the full [text of this guideline](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/).  I must say that in my personal opinion, many principles in this guideline are far more than disability access. Many remarks are common sense for a good user interface design, and **not only for web** applications.

This WCAG guideline was in the meantime promoted to international [ISO 40500 standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=58625) and the European standardization organisations made it to an [EN 301549 standard](http://www.etsi.org/news-events/news/754-new-european-standard-on-accessibility-requirements-for-public-procurement-of-ict-products-and-services) for **ICT products and services**.

So in conclusion, if you'd follow the WCAG it should help you to ensure accessibility at the large, to justify compliance with UK DDA, but also to claim compliance with several international standards.